# Creation failed error when trying to create a JSON file as the application first loads

Tags: android, dart, android-emulator, flutter

I am trying to create a method that is called when the application loads up. This method will create several JSON files in the applications document directory. However, when I run this through the Android Studio Emulator, I am getting the following error:

**Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

createFile() async {
  //Get device document directory path
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

  //Create savedSettings.json File
  if (File('$directory/savedSettings.json').existsSync()) {
    print("This file already exists");
  } else {
    File('$directory/savedSettingsTest.json').create(recursive: true);
  }
}
```

**Error:**

> Dart Error: Unhandled exception: FileSystemException: Creation failed, path = 'Directory: '' (OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to request for permissions first.

You can use this package :  https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions

This is the permission you have to add in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

And this is the enum you'll have to use

```
WriteExternalStorage
```

Here you have the sample code:

```
 https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_permissions#-example-tab-
```

Don't forget to extract the path of the `Directory` :

```
 final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
 final String path = directory.path;
 File("$path/savedSettings.json")
```

Comment: Thank you, I will have a look into this. If I wanted to read values from the files my application has create do I need the `ReadExternalStorage`

Comment: yes, and you need to add this permission on your manifest: android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: I am still getting the same error. When I print `getPermissionStatus` for the read & write, I get the following in the console: `PermissionStatus.authorized`

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I do have one more quick question. If I'm using a Emulator, where can I find that file I just created on my pc. When I print `path` I get `/data/...` which I cant seem to find.